# Backup Identity Platform Tenants

Tags: google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-identity

I am looking for a way to backup the tenants in Google Identity Platform (Firebase auth). For users I can use the importUsers function, but there does not seem to be an equivalent for tenants. Additionally when creating a tenant individually, it does not allow for the tenantId to be specified.

Is there any way to backup and restore the tenant data?

Comment: They provide you with CRUD APIs for tenants. Also all the user management APIs are available per tenant. I don't see why you can't backup tenants and their users if that is something you need to do.

Comment: @bojeil I am using said APIs. The API's don't allow you to explicitly set the tenant ID when creating a tenant. Therefore all references in remote data sources to that tenant ID are invalid as the restored tenant does not have the same ID

Comment: It doesn't exist today. Open a feature request here: https://issuetracker.google.com/